# How to run execution file of Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I write a C++ program. It can be run by visual studio in Debug mode, but when i click the .exe file in the path: C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\NewProj\Debug, it will show "Fail to open the file". I don't know why. My program read some text from a .txt file, after doing some processes, some texts will be output to another file.
Thanks:)

Comment: Maybe your program can't find path to the .txt file.

Comment: But if it can't find the path to the .txt file, the debug mode will find the error.

Comment: You may specified the file name as command line argument in the properties window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching from debug mode to release mode. Then from the menu in Visual Studio: Clean solution and rebuild the solution. If you get the same error try looking through the event viewer to see a more detailed exception.